# Lower semicontinuous and convex envelope

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations, semicontinuity

L.Ambrosio, in paper [1] writes:

> Let $g:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a function (...)
>
> for every $s\in\mathbb{R}$, $z\in\mathbb{R}^n$; we denote, with a slight abuse of notation, by $g^{**}$ the function defined by
>
> $$g^{**}(s,z) = [g(s,\cdot)]^{**}(z)$$
>
> (...) where $^{**}$ denotes the **lower semicontinous and convex envelope**.

My question is: What exactly does "lower semicontinuous and convex envelope" mean? If you calculate the convex envelope of $g(s,\cdot)$ you end up with a function $C(g)(s,\cdot):\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ which is convex, and therefore lower semicontinuous.

[1] *Ambrosio, Luigi*, Relaxation of autonomous functionals with discontinuous integrands, Ann. Univ. Ferrara, Nuova Ser., Sez. VII 34, 21-47 (1988). [ZBL0691.49011](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0691.49011).

Comment: I'll look at the paper as soon as I get a chance, but my immediate thought is, might he mean "for each $s$ the convex envelope of $g(s,\cdot)$" (which is lower semicontinous in $s$)?

Comment: A convex function on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is always continuous. In fact it is locally Lipschitz continuous so why talking about lower semicontinuity? I believe this might be because Ambrosio refers to a general fact that the convex envelope of a lower semicontinuous function on a compact convex set is lower semicontinuous, see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2221026. But I am not sure.

Comment: @PiotrHajlasz: Also, It is possible that Ambrosio refers to  **biconjugate** of a function, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_conjugate#Biconjugate.

Comment: Thanks for the paper. I notice that we are soon considering $g(u,v)$ where $u$ and $v$ are functions in $L^p(\Omega)$. Maybe he is really thinking of the lower semicontinuous and convex envelope of the function $v \mapsto g(u,v)$?

Comment: @NikWeaver That is what i though initially. I suppose that's what he's thinking about, the only thing that sounded a bit odd to me was the words he uses... every convex function is continuous and hence lower semicontinuous as Piotr Hajlasz pointed out. If that is what he is trying to say, I wonder why he tries to emphasise the lower semicontinuity.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Mahdi: For a proper function $g \colon H \to (- \infty, \infty]$, where $H$ is a Hilbert space (this even makes sense in a reflexive Banach space, but one has to replace $H$ by $H^*$ sometimes in the sequel), $g^{**}(x) = \sup_{y \in H} \langle x, y \rangle - g^*(y)$ is the [biconjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_conjugate#Biconjugate) of $g$ (where $g^*$ is the [convex conjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_conjugate#Definition) of $g$), which is *convex and lower semicontinuous*, because it is the supremum of the collection of affine (and hence convex and continuous) functions $f_{y}(x) := \langle x, y \rangle - g^*(y)$ for $y \in H$ with $g^*(y) < \infty$. We have $g^{**} \le g$ with equality if and only if $g$ is proper, convex and lower semicontinuous.
If $\text{dom}(g^*) := \{ x \in H: g^*(x) \in \mathbb R \} \ne \emptyset$, then $g^{**}$ is the largest convex and lower semicontinuous function minorizing $g$ (Prop. 9.8(i) together with Prop. 13.39 in Bauschke and Combettes' book [*Convex Analysis and Monotone Operators in Hilbert spaces*](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4419-9467-7) in chapter 13.

Since this has nothing to do with $H = \mathbb R^d$, the Lipschitzian properties of convex functions in $\mathbb R^d$ are a red herring.

Comment: One nitpick: for the improper function $g \equiv +\infty$ we have $g^* \equiv -\infty$ and $g^{**} = g \equiv +\infty$.

Comment: @gerw You're right, I added proper at the beginning. Thank you!